# Multi tenant database queue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, queue, laravel-5.4, multi-tenant

I need to pass a job to queue in a multi-tenant laravel setup. It is working fine with tenant connection(tenant) up to job dispatch. Once the job gets dispatched to job class it will take the default connection(pgsql) instead of tenant connection(tenant).

This is my controller

```
public function push_queue($ids)
    {
        $params['title']='Test';
        $params['body']='Push Notification Body';
        $params['users_id']=$ids;
        $job = (new PushNotification($params));
        //$this->dispatch($job);
        $connection = \Queue::connection('tenant');
        //dd($connection);
        $connection->pushOn('push', $job);
        //dispatch(new PushNotification($params))->onConnection('tenant')->onQueue('push');
        // $job = (new PushNotification($params))->onQueue('PushNotification');
        // $this->dispatch($job);
        //\Queue::connection('tenant')->push(new PushNotification($params));
        //dispatch(new PushNotification($params));
}
```

This is my PushNotification.php job class file

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use App\Jobs\PushNotification;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use App\Hepclasses\PushNotificationClass;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class PushNotification implements ShouldQueue
{

    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $connection='tenant';
    protected $params;
    protected $push_notification;
    public function __construct($params)
    {
        $this->params=$params;
        $this->push_notification = new PushNotificationClass();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        \Log::info(\DB::getDatabaseName());
        $push_result = $this->push_notification->send($this->params);
        return $push_result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use laravel horizon or specify the name of the tenant on config file